# VHDL and clocks 50Mz to 25Mhz

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I'm making a clock divider in VHDL. My input clock frequency is 50Mhz and I started by making a 25Mhz output with the following:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
 USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
 USE IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY CLK25 IS
    PORT(clk_in,rst   : IN      std_logic;
          clk_out         : OUT std_logic);
END ENTITY CLK25;

ARCHITECTURE behav OF CLK25 IS
SIGNAL clk_in_set  : integer RANGE 1000000000 DOWNTO 0 := 50000000;
SIGNAL clk_out_set : integer RANGE 1000000000 DOWNTO 0 := 25000000;

BEGIN 
CLK1                :   PROCESS (clk_in,rst) IS
  VARIABLE  cnt     :   unsigned(31 DOWNTO 0);
  VARIABLE clk_tmp  :   std_logic;
  VARIABLE clk_set    :   unsigned(31 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
clk_set := to_unsigned(clk_in_set/(clk_out_set*4),32); --< x4 to account for   process time delay
    IF  (rst = '0') THEN 
          cnt := (OTHERS => '0');
          clk_tmp := '0';
    ELSIF rising_edge(clk_in) THEN
        IF cnt = clk_set THEN
            clk_tmp := not(clk_tmp);
            cnt := (OTHERS => '0');
        ELSE cnt := cnt + 1;
        END IF;
    END IF;
    clk_out <= clk_tmp;
END PROCESS CLK1;
END ARCHITECTURE behav;
```

it works fine in simulation and b-test as far as can see. ->Although the usual math I know, don't really stack up <-- VHDL guru float point please! 
Any way I wanted to tidy the model up a bit and make a clock that could be user definable, with 2 parameters been entered (x and (Z # Y))

```
(clk_in_set(X)/(clk_out_set(Z) # Y )
```

is this possible? The order of the operators doesn't matter only the relation to time and frequency so for example : x  = 50000000 = input frequency and z = 25000000 = output frequency. I think this question can be solved by pure mathematics, but it is for VHDL application, hence the post. The process statement makes the math more confusing.

No wait statements please it is completely unrealistic of definable.

Comment: Unless you are planning tochange clock frequencies while the hardware is running, make `clk_in_set, clk_out_set` constants and derive `clk_set` from them as another constant. Better still, you can use physical units to make the calculations more obvious. Related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/124264/how-do-you-set-the-time-resolution-in-synplify

Comment: Hi that is close to what i intended to do, have a input that whould define the scroll speed of a display. Input value being frequency. I thought it would be an easy equation to figure out from a input clk of 50mhz. But no and the extra period needed by the counter makes the math more frustrating. The second parameter i added to make things easier . Never got there though! :(

Answer (score 3):

Generating clock with logic is a very bad and error-prone habit (gated clocks). The 'clock' signal you generate that way is indeed just a data signal with an undefined routing delay skew to the synchronous elements it is driving. Please refer to your vendor's FPGA datasheet or user guide and lookup what clock generation components are available (PLL, MMCM, DCM, ...) and use them. This might save you a whole lotta trouble.

Comment: Also consider what the 25MHz clock is to be used for. To save on the number of clock trees you generate, you could just generate a clock enable that toggles on the 50MHz clock and use that to enable logic at a rate of 25MHz.

Answer (score 2):

Your original design seems a little overkill with all those variables etc. I agree with earlier posters that you are basically just looking for a clock divider by 2.

Just a quick example of a clock divider:

```
proces(clk, rst)
begin
    if rst = '1' then
        clk_out <= '0';
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
        clk_out <= not(clk_out);
    end if;
end process;
```

But as said this might not be ok for the physical implementation. You would probably like to instantiate a flipflop from library so that you get a hard coded instance port (clk_out) in which you can create a new clock source. That way you get 50/50 clock cycle on the real silicon.

Dividing by 4, 8 etc. can be achieved by just cascading these dividers. Or planB is to create a simple counter from 0..N and just inver the clk_out every time the count hits N. N would set the clock rate. This also enables you to get more flexible clock rates, though not all of them would be 50/50 clocks! But in this scheme again it's important to use a hardcoded flipflop so that you have a solid instance name in which to use as a clock root.

Comment: Does a clock divider need a reset?

Comment: Without reset the clk_out will be 'x' in the simulation. Hence **not(clk_out)** would still be 'x'. So no clock output ;)

On the silicon in theory the reset is not needed. But it's nice to know the phase of signals and always have a clean start with reset. Not to mention testability issues with ASICs. Of course FPGAs are different breed. In those guys you could skip the reset and just use the init value for signals from the declaration? Like this: **signal clk_out : std_logic := '0';**

Comment: Yes that's reset theory, but you are designing a T-FF. This reset increase the reset tree on FPGA and ASIC. There is no need to reset a clock divider. All registers in a design should have a default value.

Comment: I don't know if the reset/clock tree is really a problem if the utilization is no extremely high. Most likely there will be clock routes left unused in the FPGA anyway (though I am no FPGA expert).

With ASICs there are probably design guidelines in the company/vendor that forbid the use of non-reset logic. And of course, in ASICs the reset is the only init value ;)

Comment: The reset tree can have an impact on the timing and on the design desitiy. This can be improved by using a clock network for the reset. A Clock, Reset and ClockEnable form a control set. More resets usually mean more control sets which can hinder slice compaction. It's possible to have init values in ASICs too. FFs can be designed to flip to a specific value after power up.

Comment: While yes for a 25Mhz clock a simple /2 works, I was more interested if anyone knew of a an equation that would allow a user or hardware to define a clock speed on 2 parameters. The equation would also need to take into consideration the delay caused by the process as it updates any signal. The snip it shown in the original post is from a scroll speed control for a display.

Comment: Ok, sorry I must have misunderstod the original question a little bit. Maybe instead of clk dividing you would be better off with constant clk rate and some programmable counter that creates enable signals? So the faster the scroll speed, the faster the enable rate would be.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a 25 MHz clock from a 50 MHz input clock, you hast have to divide the input clock by two. This can be achieved by a single flip-flop which is toggled at every rising edge of the input clock.

You design fulfill this if `clk_set` is 0.
Moreover, your design supports dividers wich are multiples of two.